# How can I convert a custom PyTorch model (model.pt) to a Huggingface Transformers model, so I can load it with from_pretrained()?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I pretrained a custom NLP model in PyTorch and saved the last checkpoint as "model.pt". Now I want to integrate this model in the Huggingface Transformers environment, so it can be finetuned with different heads etc.
How do I convert this PyTorch-model to a Huggingface-model? As far as I understand it, I have to somehow generate a set of configuration files?

Comment: What model have you trained? Is it a transformer? A model consists of code and weights. `from_pretrained` allows you to create the model code from the configuration files and the classes provided by the transformers library and load your weights into it.

Comment: Yes, it's a transformer with a modified attention module

Comment: You basically have to do the same as when huggingface is adding a new architecture. Just look for the PR on github and check what they did.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that. Here I found an additional tutorial on the complete process: https://huggingface.co/transformers/add_new_model.html