# How to automatically convert a PyTorch model to a HuggingFace model?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

Say I created a Pytorch model:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        
        self.model_1_encoder = RobertaModel.from_pretrained('roberta-base')
        self.model_2_encoder = RobertaModel.from_pretrained('roberta-base')

        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.linear_model_1_out = nn.Linear(768, 512)
        self.linear_model_2_out = nn.Linear(768, 512)
    
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(512, 512)
        self.linear4 = nn.Linear(512, 1)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        question_input_ids, attn_mask, xyz_input_ids, xyz_attention_mask = torch.tensor(x['input_ids']), torch.tensor(x['attention_mask']), torch.tensor(x['xyz_ids']), torch.tensor(x['xyz_mask'])
        model_1_outputs = self.model_1_encoder(question_input_ids, attention_mask=attn_mask)
        model_2_outputs = self.model_2_encoder(xyz_input_ids, attention_mask = xyz_attention_mask)
        model_1_outputs = self.dropout(model_1_outputs[0])
        model_2_outputs = self.dropout(model_2_outputs[0])

        model_2_outputs = torch.sum(model_2_outputs, dim=0) 
        model_2_outputs = torch.unsqueeze(model_2_outputs, 0) 
        model_2_outputs = model_2_outputs.repeat(model_1_outputs.shape[0], 1, 1) 

        model_1_outputs = self.linear_model_1_out(model_1_outputs)
        model_2_outputs = self.linear_model_2_out(model_2_outputs)

        model_1_and_xyz_sum = model_2_outputs + model_1_outputs 
        outputs = self.dropout(model_1_and_xyz_sum)
        outputs = outputs[:,0,:].view(-1,512) 
        outputs = torch.relu(self.linear3(outputs))
        outputs = self.dropout(outputs)
        outputs = torch.relu(self.linear4(outputs))
        return outputs

model = Model()
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69077472/how-can-i-convert-a-custom-pytorch-model-model-pt-to-a-huggingface-transformer) SO question I understand that I need to create a config file for the Pytorch model that will be loaded by the model. They referenced [How to add a model to Transformers?](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/add_new_model), which if I understands correctly requires manual writing of each layer in my custom model in addition to various other inputs and steps. I also found [this](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/convert-pytorch-model-to-huggingface-transformer/16965) question on their forum, which referenced [this](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/custom_models#sharing-custom-models), which had even more steps to complete in order to convert the Pytorch model.

How can I automatically convert my Pytorch model to a Hugginface model so that I can use their `Trainer` class (in addition to other functionalities like the `DataCollator`, etc.)?

**Potential optimal pseudocode:**

```
my_pytorch_model = Model()
my_huggingface_model = Custom_huggingface_Model.load_model(my_pytorch_model)
```

Comment: I would say go through the documentation [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_sharing)